# What does "in a wide range" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "in many forms"?

"In the 2004-2006 cycle, long-term yields rose before the Fed hiked rates as investors anticipated the changes, but then fell after the actual increase in the Fed funds rate began. In the current cycle, 10-year Treasury bond yields have traded **in a wide range** since the Fed first began to move the Federal funds rate above zero in December 2015. Yet despite three rate hikes, bond yields are about where they were when the cycle began."

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/3-reasons-to-own-bonds-when-the-fed-is-raising-rates-2017-4

Comment: It means that the value has *ranged widely*, that is, that it's moved across a long distance.  Does that help?

Comment: @haile, we need to see some dictionary effort on your part. Many of your questions could be answered by a few minutes of effort of your own.  The actual problem with the sentence you quote is that the **yields** are not traded. As I mentioned a few questions ago, business writing is largely crapola.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: It's not as simple as you think. For a non-native speaker, sometimes a dictionary can't help. And there's no reason why I have to post a question without doing some research first, which takes less time than waiting for a correct answer.

Comment: @haile: You mean to say it's not as *quick and easy* for you to consult a dictionary as to ask here.  But we're not a dictionary service, and your questions are close-worthy. I'm not the first person to have pointed this out to you.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I meant  the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

This *range* is about ***trading range***. It's a common term in trading markets (e.g., stock trading, bond trading, future trading, commodity trading).

I'll assume that you know the basics of trading, how it's like trading stocks, bonds, and so on, in a market. The price of a stock or bond always moves.

The most important price data for traders are Open, Close, High, and Low, along with other data such as Volume. The data may be daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly, or any length of time.

**Range** is the difference (also known as *spread*) between the High (i.e., highest price) and Low (lowest price) traded in a given period of time.

So, when something has been traded ***in a wide range***, it means that the difference between the highest and lowest price points in that period of time is large.